# Использование dropbox api в Android

Tags: dropbox, android, java

DropBox API + Android

Хотел спросить кто нибудь пользовался [DropBox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#android). На сайте есть инструкция и пример пример не запускается, а по инструкции не совсем ясно как произвести **аутентификацию**!. Может кто подскажет или объяснит.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final String FILENAME = "file.txt";

private LinearLayout mDisplay;

private static final String TAG = "log";

private static final String APP_KEY="xxx";
private static final String APP_SECRET="yyy";

private static final AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;

final static private String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
final static private String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
final static private String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";

DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>mApi;

private boolean mLoggedIn;

private Button btnAuto;
private Button btnSave;
private Button btnDownload;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "Метод onCreate");

    AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
    mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
    mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(MainActivity.this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkAppKeySetup();

    btnAuto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAuto);

    btnAuto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // This logs you out if you're logged in, or vice versa
            if (mLoggedIn) {
                Log.d(TAG, "if(mLoggedIn");
                logOut();
            } else {
                // Start the remote authentication
                mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(MainActivity.this);
                Log.d(TAG, "else mLoggedIn");
            }
        }
    });

btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AccessTokenPair aTP = new AccessTokenPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        writeFile();
        readFile();
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("/data/data/com.example.db_test2/files/file.txt");
            Log.d(TAG, "File file...");
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Log.d(TAG, "file.lenght "+file.length());
            Entry newEntry = mApi.putFile("/Task for you/file.txt", inputStream,
                    file.length(), null, null);
            Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,inputStream.toString());

            // User has unlinked, ask them to link again here.
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "User has unlinked.");
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
        }

});

btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        readFile();

        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(FILENAME);

            Log.d(TAG, file.toString());
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Log.d(TAG, outputStream.toString());
            DropboxFileInfo info = mApi.getFile(FILENAME, null, outputStream, null);
            Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " );

            // /path/to/new/file.txt now has stuff in it.
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while downloading.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }

    }
});

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
    AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session;

    String[] stored = getKeys();
    if (stored != null) {
        AccessTokenPair accessToken = new AccessTokenPair(stored[0], stored[1]);
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE, accessToken);

    } else {
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair, ACCESS_TYPE);

    }

    return session;
}

private String[] getKeys() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
    String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
    if (key != null && secret != null) {
        String[] ret = new String[2];
        ret[0] = key;
        ret[1] = secret;
        return ret;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
private void checkAppKeySetup() {
    // Check to make sure that we have a valid app key
    if (APP_KEY.startsWith("CHANGE") ||
            APP_SECRET.startsWith("CHANGE")) {
        showToast("You must apply for an app key and secret from developers.dropbox.com, and add them to the DBRoulette ap before trying it.");
        finish();
        return;
    }}

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }

    private void logOut() {
        // Remove credentials from the session
        mApi.getSession().unlink();

        // Clear our stored keys
        clearKeys();
        // Change UI state to display logged out version
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }
    private void clearKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
    }

    private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        if (loggedIn) {
            btnAuto.setText("Unlink from Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnAuto.setText("Link with Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    void writeFile() {
        try {
          // отрываем поток для записи
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
              openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE)));
          // пишем данные
          bw.write("Содержимое файла");
          bw.write("Check it");
          // закрываем поток
          bw.close();
          Log.d(TAG, "Файл записан");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    void readFile() {
        try {
          // открываем поток для чтения
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
              openFileInput(FILENAME)));
          String str = "";
          // читаем содержимое
          while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, str);
          }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение есть!
Я забыл добавить onResume(){}
И реализовать получения токена, ужас как я сразу не понял этого..